# Animate offset with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm doing this :

```
source.offset({ top: top + 10 + (current)*60 , left: left + 10 });
```

What I would like to do is to animate the move. So I've done :

```
source.animate({left: left + 10, top:top + 10 + (current)*60}, 500, function() {    // Animation complete.});
```

But it's not going to the right place. Although with the first version it was ok.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: some more code like the corresponding html and a little info about what source is, could help.

Comment: What do you mean with "it's not going to the right place"? Too much on the left, on the right, too high, too low, it doesn't move? A snippet of the HTML code would make it easier to determine what's the issue. :)

Answer (score 4):

I'm no expert but I think animate() and css() can change offset relative to the parent.. like position() while offset() gives you the offset from the whole document..
maybe thats what confuses?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$("#source").animate({left: (left + 10), top:(top + 10 + ((current)*60))}, 500, function()
 { //comments });
```

For more info, see http://forum.jquery.com/topic/offset-with-animate

Comment: Try $("#source").animate({left: (left + 10), top:(top + 10 + ((current)*60))}, 500, function() { //comments });